# Push notification without server

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to know if its possible to send a notification from within a game while it is in the background without the need of a server part?

I searched in google but i did not find anything helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any one is intrested, this how i ended up pushing local notifications for free and without a server part for both android and ios.

For android i used the plugin suggested by Doh09:

After adding the plugin this is the simple code i used:

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        NotificationManager.CancelAll();
        DateTime dateToNotify = DateTime.Now;
        dateToNotify = dateToNotify.AddHours(hoursToAdd);
        dateToNotify = dateToNotify.AddMinutes(minsToAdd);
        dateToNotify = dateToNotify.AddSeconds(secondsToAdd);
        TimeSpan time = dateToNotify - DateTime.Now;
        NotificationManager.SendWithAppIcon(time, title, body, Color.red, NotificationIcon.Bell);
#endif
```

For IOS i used the UNITYENGINE.IOS and this is the code:

```
#if UNITY_IOS
        UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationServices.ClearLocalNotifications();
        UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationServices.CancelAllLocalNotifications();
        DateTime dateToNotify = DateTime.Now;

        dateToNotify = dateToNotify.AddHours(hoursToAdd);

        dateToNotify = dateToNotify.AddMinutes(minsToAdd);

        dateToNotify = dateToNotify.AddSeconds(secondsToAdd);

        UnityEngine.iOS.LocalNotification notif = new UnityEngine.iOS.LocalNotification();
        notif.fireDate = dateToNotify;
        notif.alertTitle = title;
        notif.alertBody = body;
        notif.repeatInterval = UnityEngine.iOS.CalendarUnit.Day;
        UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationServices.ScheduleLocalNotification(notif);

#endif
```

Hope this help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

This free asset should be able to do it for the Android OS: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/simple-android-notifications-free-68626

Haven't come across a native Unity way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OneSignal for push notification.
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/unity-sdk-setup
This SDK is too easy to intergate